# Invalid value for field 'resource.subnetwork. Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

As part of GCE configuration, Using CCM(Cloud Controller Manager) Kubernetes API to launch this loadbalancer.  I have configured a custom VPC network and custom subnet and tried launching a Internal loadbalancer to publish my services within the project.

Problem is creation of Internal LB got failed.

system          50s         Normal    EnsuringLoadBalancer           service/ABC                   Ensuring load balancer

system          59s         Warning   SyncLoadBalancerFailed         service/ABC                   Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.subnetwork': ''. Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode., invalid

Manifest files as following annotation

```
cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

Any suggestions to solve this error are most welcome?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the annotation "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"" should allow you to create an Internal TCP/UDP Load balancer as states this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#background): "GKE creates an internal TCP/UDP load balancer
when you add the cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal" annotation;
otherwise, GKE creates an external network load balancer."

On the other hand, have you tried to create a service using the annotation as the [information states] [2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#create)

```
"apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilb-service
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
......."
```

As a complement to the aforementioned information seems like the load balancer subnet can be selected according to
"Load balancer subnet" [section](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#lb_subnet) by using the annotation "networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet" as a side note.
The subnet must exist before it is referenced by the Service. The example provided is as follows:

```
"apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilb-service
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet: "gke-vip-subnet"
......
"
```

Hope this information helps you with this behavior.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this and responding back. But still the problem is not solved.

Comment: The problem was observed as part of  GCE, i meant not on GKE, not sure if the annotations are applicable for both. Even after including above suggested changes still the issues can be observed. I have added the traces below.

Comment: 15s         Normal    EnsuringLoadBalancer           service/ABC               Ensuring load balancer                      
15s         Warning   ILBCustomSubnetOptionIgnored   service/ABC               Internal LoadBalancer CustomSubnet options ignored as the feature gate is disabled.
5s          Warning   SyncLoadBalancerFailed         service/ABC               Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.subnetwork': ''. Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode., invalid

Comment: In above manifest it has to provide a support for custom Virtual network and custom Subnet, it seems it's not able to get the SubNetwork, I'm not sure on GCP networking where to look at?

Comment: I tried out the doc [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) using both annotations `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` and `networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet: "subnet"` and it does not display any issue for subnet. Not sure if could be related an issue with either cloud controller manager and feature gate as the error states. Seems like feature gates are available for Alpha cluster [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#alpha_cluster)

Comment: Also considering GKE versioning since [per](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#service_parameters) Load Balancer is on Beta in Beta in GKE 1.17+ and 1.16.8-gke.10+ and General Availability on GA in GKE 1.17.9-gke.600+

Comment: On the other hand [per restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#restrictions_for_internal_tcpudp_load_balancers) "For clusters running Kubernetes version 1.7.3 and earlier, you could only use internal TCP/UDP load balancers with auto-mode subnets, but with Kubernetes version 1.7.4 and later, you can use internal load balancers with custom-mode subnets in addition to auto-mode subnets"

Comment: Many thanks for the response @cochitoo. Apologies for responding a bit late. Yes, this could be a problem with cloud controller manager. I 'm currently trying to launch these load balancer by using the CCM API and may be that causing these traces to appear. Also, I'm using Microk8s( a CNCF Certified) Kubernetes Offerings. Version is 1.18.

Comment: few more observations, if we don't use the custom VPC and custom subnet things works as expected lb are created and launched. This problem is only observed with the custom subnets inside custom VPC Network.. How safe and reliable is the auto-subnet management as these publish services will serve other VPC Network, don't you feel the problem with the VPC peering and extra burden can trigger ??

Comment: In my opinion could affect that it is not possible to specify the ranges desired [per](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#subnet-ranges) "When an auto mode VPC network is created, one subnet from each region is automatically created within it." 

For VPC peering while it does not fall on transitive [peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions) scenario it should work well.